# AuthorizeAttribute v Application_AuthenticateRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorize-attribute

We want to authorize users and if they are authorized we want to add their roles and permissions to the user and add that to the IPrinciple

We have 2 ways of doing this one is to do it in global.asax  Application_AuthenticateRequest the other is to create an attribute that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute

Is there any gleaming good choice here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC you should prefer a custom authorize attribute. If on the other hand you want this code to be reusable with classic ASP.NET applications then you could use `Application_AuthenticateRequest` or write a custom HttpModule and use the AuthenticateRequest event.

Comment: yeah - what my gut was telling me. Any info on why it is preferred?

Comment: @iwayneo, one thing that springs to mind is that ASP.NET MVC abstracts for you many of the HttpContext specific classes making your code easier to unit test in isolation. If you put your code in Global.asax, you will probably be working with static and sealed classes which personally I don't like working with. That's why I prefer the MVC way of doing things. But of course that's subjective. Both are possible. I am expressing only my personal preference here.